# Have .clangd configure differently based on windows vs linux

Tags: clangd

I have a cmake C++ project. I access the project directory from WSL2-Ubuntu and MINGW64 git-bash on my Windows machine. I have a separate build folder for each: `build-wsl` and `build-win` respectively.

I'm trying to configure the project with the clangd LSP for neovim. I know I can create a `.clangd` config at the project root to tell clangd where to look for the `compile_commands.json`. I'd like to do something like this:

```
If: WIN32
    CompileFlags:
        CompilationDatabase: build-win/
Else:
    CompilationFlags:
        CompilationDatabase: build-wsl/
```

Is there a way to achieve that? If so, how? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any support for this in the config file syntax itself.

One thing to consider might be having your build system generate the `.clangd` file with different contents on different platforms (then the platform-checking logic would go into the cmake script). Though, if the location of `CompilationDatabase` is the only thing that differs between the platforms, a simpler alternative might be to just have your build system symlink (or copy) the `compile_commands.json` file from the respective location to the project root, where clangd will find it automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Though one issue is that I'm accessing the same directory from both WSL and git bash. I just tried symlinking build-win/ -> build/ in git bash, but the symlink also appeared my WSL shell. With the cmake logic, copying out compile_commands.json to project root from one shell, would wipe out the file created by the other shell. So I would need to rerun cmake every time I switched shells. Something that came to mind just now, is I could use $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/clang/config.yaml on each machine.